# How long would it take to run an algorithm with 10-100 quadrillion steps on a 1 ghz processor?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, combinations

This is my first question on SO, please let me know if it's inappropriate/off topic. I've made the question above fairly general, but the specific problem I am having is as follows:

I want to write a piece of Java code that generates a list of all possible combinations of states that result in an electoral college tie. The shortest possible list would contain 12 states and the longest possible list would contain 38 states. I've done some (very) rough calculations and all of the possible combinations comes to (maybe) 10 quadrillion. I'm still in the planning stage for the algorithm, but it's a given that 10 quadrillion is an absolute lower limit for the number of steps required, and I imagine the real number will be significantly higher.

I'm fairly new to programming and want to know if it's even worth writing this code - one rough calculation suggested that the algorithm would take about 30 years to complete (!). However, I based this calculation on the MIPs (million instructions per second) value suggested by wikipedia, and I have no idea how accurate that really is (or, indeed, what actually counts as an "instruction" for these purposes).

Many thanks for reading and/or answering :)

Comment: First question: what are you planning on *doing* with the list? (Obviously not going to fit in memory or on disk...)

Comment: A statement you have in Java will end up to be several instructions (several cycles) for the CPU actually. How did you even make the calculation? How do you know how many cpu cycles will you need?

Comment: @JonSkeet This is a fair question and one I had already thought of - the answer is that I don't really want the 10-quadrillion long list of lists, I only want a (much shorter) list of the combinations that actually result in ties.

Comment: @KorayTugay The short answer is: I don't know how many CPU cycles I'll need, only that it would be at the very least 10 quadrillion and in actuality more. As for how I made the calculation, I worked out how many possible combinations there were for lists of 12, 38 and 25 then took the mean and multiplied it by 26. Sloppy, I know, but I just wanted a ballpark figure (assuming a very large ballpark)

Answer (score 3):

A 1 GHz processor has a clock that ticks one billion times a second. The clock ticking is used to allow flow of signal through the system. The theoretical maximum number of operations (of any kind) that can be performed is therefore 1 billion operations per second. To perform 10 quadrillion operations, the theoretical minimum time is 10 quadrillion divided by 1 billion, which gives 10 million (seconds). If my calculations are correct, that comes out to around 116 days. In practice, you won't get quite that much performance, but with a modern pipelined processor you should actually do well, say at least 50% for well-optimized assembler. So for a single modern 1 GHz processor I think 200 days is a very reasonable guess for integer operations like what you'd expect in combinatorics.

Now, your "step" might be lots of machine instructions. This seems probable for any sufficiently complex "step". If a single "step" is 100 machine instructions (a fairly beefy "step") then we're really talking more like 20,000 days or 54 years.

Now, what can we do? Well, generating combinations is well-suited to parallel programming. If you were able to get some time at a supercomputing center and ran this job on 1000 cores each running at 3 GHz, for instance, the run would take about 7 days to complete - maybe 10 to account for the non-parallel work.

Alternatively, if you can work out a clever algorithm to avoid branching, you could get a few of NVIDIA GTX 980s and run it at home. You get around 2,000 cores each running at ~1 GHz per graphics card, so a few of these bad boys will speed up your task immensely (again, if you can write your program in a way that is efficient on a graphics card - that is the hard part).

Verdict? Doable, but costly and/or difficult - especially difficult if you are not comfortable writing massively parallel programs which will be required to make what you are hoping to do any kind of feasible.

Comment: Thank you! This covers pretty much everything I wanted to know. I am probably not going to run this algorithm for the next 6 months/54 years so I guess I will just have to wonder :)

Answer (score 1):

Calculating out of basic logic, theoretically 1 GHz can do 1 billion calculations/second.

Time for 10 quadrillion calculations would mean, 10 quadrillion/1 billion

So calculate it through and you will find that it will take approximetly 115 days to complete

```
10,000,000,000,000,000 / 1,000,000,000 = 10,000,000 seconds
10,000,000 seconds = 166,667 minutes
166,667 minutes = 2778 hours
2778 hours = 115 days
```

But this is all theoretical